# Negative Multinomial Distribution as a sum of random variables

Tags: distributions, negative-binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution

Given a random variable $x$ distributed according to a Negative Binomial distribution with dispersion parameter $r$, it can be seen as the sum of $r$ Geometric distributions.

But given the Negative Multinomial distribution (the multivariate version of the Negative Binomial) is it also equivalent to the sum of something?